# Unable to see file in certain folder but can elsewhere

Tags: wordpress, lets-encrypt, 1and1

I am in the process of trying to verify a Let's Encrypt SSL cert on a clients Wordpress site hosted on 1and1. However, the file is apparently not found/fails to verify.

I have placed other files in the same directory (.well-known/acme-challenge/) and have the same issue - Wordpress returns:

*The page you are looking for is temporarily unavailable.
Please try again later.*

Moving the files 1 directory up (.well-known/) makes them accessible to the outside world but the files have to be in the acme-challenge folder I believe.

I have checked permissions and the 2 directories share the same permission, owner, group etc.

Does anyone know what I've missed here?

Thanks

Comment: Check the web server error log.

Comment: I don’t have access to any error logs that I can see. I have a logs folder within my users directory that contains access and ftp logs but that’s it.

Comment: Since you are using 1&1 *WordPress Hosting*, you might be fighting with 1&1's specific server setup for WordPress. It's possible you will get the best answer from their support.

Comment: Yup, they don't allow it because they want you to buy an SSL cert from them and only them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not able to do this with 1&1 as they have made it so you can only use SSL certs you have purchased from them.

Avoid.